# Same ID generation for same users in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, graph, tree, graph-theory

In Spark, we need to generate ID column such that if multiple users have the same Emails Or Phones then they should be assigned with the same ID.

| email | phone | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a@b.com | 123 | 1 |
| c@d.com | 123 | 1 |
| e@g.com | 234 | 1 |
| e@g.com | 123 | 1 |
| a@b.com |  | 1 |
| a@b.com | 789 | 1 |
| d@e.com | 9090 | 2 |
| e@g.com | 549 | 1 |
| f@e.com | 549 | 1 |
| g@e.com | 550 | 1 |
| h@e.com | 549 | 1 |
| f@e.com | 551 | 1 |
| g@e.com | 551 | 1 |
| z@e.com | 519 | 3 |

We tried strongly connected component from graph frame in pyspark and it works for about ~30 million records. The problem is we have about 100 million records and we need an optimal solution for that.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so far if possible

Comment: We are trying to solve entity resolution using graph frames strongly connected component algorithm. The reason for choosing graph structure was how the data are interlinked each other via email and phone.
We used a data frame of containing email and phone as edge and union same data frame so it would act as vertex for us and it has ID column which contains both email and phone

Comment: Another data frame was created from this data frame and id was named as src and phone number was named as dst so that it would act as a edge data frame. Then we created a graph frame using this vertex and edge. We are using strongly connected component with max iter parameter as 10. This solution works well with 15 million node but when the node size is increased to 50 million performance is quite bad. The machine we have approximately 200 GB ram and 56 core machine with 7 node. Each node having 30GB of memory.

Comment: We tweaked this configuration to 56GB node machine with 16 core each node and 8 nodes but still no performance improvement. We are using standard runtime.
Some performance improvement option we tried such as caching, persistence and join setting change and few other setting tweak.